# Can be drawable and color be combined in an android:background?

Tags: android, xml

I have the following XML file for my Android application:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"

        android:background="@color/SlideBackgroundGrey"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector">
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/heart_rate"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is on lines 6-7:

```
android:background="@color/SlideBackgroundGrey"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```

It tells me that background attribute is duplicated. Can anyone know how to combine these two or how to make the background be able the show the list and the background color I want?

Answer (score 0):

A view can only have one background drawable. If you specify a color, Android creates a `ColorDrawable` for you.

You'd need to modify the `list_selector` drawable to include a background color, if it doesn't already.

If the list_selector is as it seems a `XML` selector, you'd need to modify all the different drawables involved in the selector.

If the drawables are bitmaps, you can do it with photoshop. If they are shapes, you can specify the background color with the `<solid>` tag in the `<shape>` definition in the XML file.

Comment: Well, I modified the colors in selector's drawables but when I run the app, there is no difference, it doesn't make the update. Is there a place where I should declare the modification?

Comment: can you post one of the modified drawables so I can take a look? It should be straightahead, and you should see the changes even from eclipse UI builder, without even compling the app (if the modified state is the normal, non-clicked one). Mind that if you specify a solid background color and over it you put a non-transparent bitmap, the background will be hidden!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a drawable layer-list like this for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#7B7979" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

create this in the drawable folder and use it as background attribute

**Edit:**
This is using the icon with a rounded corner shaped background.